# MongoDB and unrecognised option '--enableEncryption'

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem when I run an image mongo with docker-compose.yml. I need to encrypt my data because it is very sensitive. My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo"
    command: ["mongod","--enableEncryption","--encryptionKeyFile", "/data/db/mongodb-keyfile"]
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data:/data/db
```

I check the mongodb-keyfile exits in data/db, ok no problem, but when I build the file, made and up the image, and te command is:

```
"docker-entrypoint.sh mongod --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile /data/db/mongodb-keyfile"
```

The status:

```
About a minute ago   Exited (2) About a minute ago
```

I show the logs and see:

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--enableEncryption'
```

I understand the error, but I don't known how to solve it. I think to make a Dockerfile with the image an ubuntu (linux whatever) and install mongo with the all configurations necessary. Or try to solved it. 
Please help me, thx.

Comment: The [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) says `--enableEncryption` is available in version 3.2, not version 3. You should probably use a newer version of MogoDB of you want to use the encryption service.

Comment: @jww The latest mongo image is version 4, the yaml `version: '3'` is for docker-compose, I think the issue is that `enableEncryption` is an enterprise only option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/), the encryption is available in **MongoDB Enterprise only**. So you need to have paid subscription to use it.

For the docker image of the enterprise version it says in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-with-docker/) that you can build it yourself:

1. Download the Docker build files for MongoDB Enterprise.

   Set `MONGODB_VERSION` to your major version of choice.

   ```
   export MONGODB_VERSION=4.0
   curl -O --remote-name-all https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/mongo/master/$MONGODB_VERSION/{Dockerfile,docker-entrypoint.sh}
   ```
2. Build the Docker container.

   Use the downloaded build files to create a Docker container image wrapped around MongoDB Enterprise. Set `DOCKER_USERNAME` to your Docker Hub username.

   ```
   export DOCKER_USERNAME=username
   chmod 755 ./docker-entrypoint.sh
   docker build --build-arg MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-enterprise --build-arg MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.com -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/mongo-enterprise:$MONGODB_VERSION .
   ```
3. Test your image.

   The following commands run mongod locally in a Docker container and check the version.

   ```
   docker run --name mymongo -itd $DOCKER_USERNAME/mongo-enterprise:$MONGODB_VERSION
   docker exec -it mymongo /usr/bin/mongo --eval "db.version()"
   ```